# Acumatica PXFormula issue reading multiple tables

Tags: acumatica

I'm using a non-persisted field on the Kit Line Specifications. The formula is really just the quantity Multiply the cost. The problem is, the std cost is held on the InventoryItems table, but average or last costs etc aren't. The formula is easy for standard costs, but trying to read the average costs as well is proving difficult. I've tried the INItemStatsTotal and the INItemCost to get the costs and nether work, have tried extra selectors to do it, and whilst the std cost is fine, the other costs are blank. As I'm totalling this to the header as well it should push the sum of the value to header, which it does when you change a std cost item, but not the others. Below is an example with a mix of ways to get the data - the dtd cost is teh only one that works. Your help is appreciated.

```
    [PXFormula(
        //typeof(Mult<Selector<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID, InventoryItem.stdCost>, INKitSpecStkDet.dfltCompQty>),
        typeof(Mult<Selector<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID
            , Switch<
                    Case<
                          Where<InventoryItem.valMethod, Equal<INValMethod.standard>>
                            , InventoryItem.stdCost
                        , Case<Where<InventoryItem.valMethod, Equal<INValMethod.average>>
                            , INItemStatsTotal.avgCost
                            //, Selector<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID, INItemCost.avgCost>
                        , Case<Where<InventoryItem.valMethod, Equal<INValMethod.specific>>
                            //, INItemCost.lastCost
                            , Selector<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID, INItemStatsTotal.lastCost>
                        , Case<Where<InventoryItem.valMethod, Equal<INValMethod.fIFO>>
                            //, INItemCost.lastCost
                            , Selector<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID, INItemStatsTotal.lastCost>
                            >>>>>>
            , INKitSpecStkDet.dfltCompQty>),
        typeof(SumCalc<INKitSpecHdrExt.usrnpTotalStockCost>))]
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a separate non-persisted field to INKitSpecStkDet if there isn't one, which will calculate the cost and then just use that field in the formula.

Comment: I tried doing that - in both InventoryItem and INKitSpecStkDet, neither of them picked up a value to even display on the form. I believe sometables tables dont get initialised, but I dont know how to force it to initialise.

Comment: Have you added that in the Field Attributes or in the PXGraph?

Comment: I added a non-persisted field to the InventoryItem and InKitSpecStkDet tables. I used the PXFormula attribute to try and get the value for the cost on the DAC. I did one field for standard cost which worked as it's on the InventoryItem table anyway. I used another field but referenced the InitemCost and another for the InitemStatsTotal to get the average cost. Both of those fields were blank. In the graph extension I can update the value in the field_selecting event, but I'd rather be able to do it in the DAC.